# How do you delete a content type in Crafter Studio?

Tags: crafter-cms

I am not seeing an obvious way to delete a content type in Crafter Studio. Do I have to do this by git commands in a shell?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it via the UI in versions < 4.0.

In version 4.0, this is supported: https://github.com/craftercms/craftercms/issues/1631

Remember, deleting content types can have negative, unintended, consequences.

For 3.x, you can delete the content type in Git/CLI and commit.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete a content-type using shell and commit manually.

1. Go to the path - cd sandbox/config/studio/content-types/page/
2. delete the contentType directory.
3. Commit the change.

Please note that deleting the content-type will have impact on the pages/ components using that particular content-type.